# android hellomap example giving exception

Tags: android

```
 06-14 22:13:33.992: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.HelloMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class com.google.android.maps.MapView
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.example.HelloMap.onCreate(HelloMap.java:16)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     ... 11 more
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:237)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     ... 21 more
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity.
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:281)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:254)
06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331):     ... 25 more
```

I had done all configuration.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.HelloMap"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

and my layout file main.xml is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="*************"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my Hellomap.java

```
public class HelloMap extends Activity {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    MapView mapView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapview);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    }



    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Something I am missing I guess, or maybe the issue is with 2.1 Google API?

Comment: Do you have the Google APIs set as the external library to use for your project rather than the regular Android library?

Comment: yeah i am using google api 2.1

Comment: and i had map.jar and android.jar

Comment: check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/7644635/779408

Answer (score 17):

i got my answere myself

just see the exception log

last lines

```
MapViews can only be created inside instances of MapActivity. 06-14 22:13:34.031: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(331): at com.google.android.maps.MapView.(MapView.java:281) 06-14 22:13:34.031:
```

that means you need to extend your activity with MapActivity not Activity i guess most of you know but i got to know now 
:)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and solved it by the following 2 steps:

1) Put the following line in the **application** (important) element of AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

2) extend MapActivity instead of Activity.

enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Here i change Activity to MapActivity.

So Instead of

```
public class HelloMap extends Activity {
```

change it to

```
public class HelloMap extends MapActivity {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in using google maps and you have set the xml and activity and you got this type of error, then it means that you have't extend your class from MapsActivity, so extend your class from mapsactivity, it will start working !

//wrong usage of activity

```
public class A extends Actvitiy
{   
 }
 //correct usage

public class A extedns MapsActivity {
 //your all program...
 }
```